# Use callback function in AJAX pure javascript

Tags: loop, javascript

I've been looking for a while, but nothing answers my question.

How can I turn this code in jQuery into pure javascript?

I need it to work for the load more that loads other posts on my WordPress site.

```
jQuery.noConflict($);
/* Funzioni AJAX */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Esegue la funzione quando avviene il click
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Init
        var that = $(this);
        var page = $(this).data('page');
        var newPage = page + 1;
        var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
        //Chiamata AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                page: page,
                action: 'ajax_script_load_more'

            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //Controllo
                if (response == 0) {
                    $('#ajax-content').append('<div class="text-center"><h3>Non sono presenti altri articoli!</h3></div>');
                    $('#loadMore').hide();
                } else {
                    that.data('page', newPage);
                    $('#ajax-content').append(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

I got as far as the following, but it still doesn't work. How do I pass the action that is a function into my functions.php file?

```
   document.querySelector('#loadMore').addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn_load_more = document.querySelector('#loadMore');
    console.log('bene!');

    var page = btn_load_more.getAttribute('data-page');
    var ajaxurl = btn_load_more.getAttribute('data-url');
    
    var newPage = page + 1;
    
    console.log(page);
    console.log(ajaxurl);
    
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'page='+page+'&action=ajax_script_load_more';
    http.open('POST', 'wp_ajax_ajax_script_load_more', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            that.data('page', newPage); 
            document.querySelector('#ajax-content').appendChild(response);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
    
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I've been looking for a while, but nothing answers my question." - sorry to hear that, but I'm sure you know the rules here - generic JS questions should be asked on Stack Overflow and not here.

Comment: However, as for the AJAX/WordPress action part, use `&action=ajax_script_load_more` and not `&callback="ajax_script_load_more"`. I.e. The parameter name is `action` and the value is the AJAX action name as registered in WordPress, e.g. via `wp_ajax_<action name>`.

Comment: I'm still new to this. I updated the code, but it still doesn't work. Could you please post the correct answer?

Comment: Actually, why must you convert the jQuery code to vanilla JS? What's the problem with using jQuery? Also, why not use the native `fetch()` function in JS? That way, it would be easier to make the AJAX request and handle its response.

Comment: I'm trying not to use the jQuery library to make my site as fast as possible using only pure javascript.

Comment: I have never used fetch, can it work for a post request with loop args?

Comment: Thank you very much, fetch did its job, thanks for leading me to the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with fetch, pure javascript. I followed this article to do it, hope it will be useful for many:
https://templateartist.com/2020/05/26/javascript-fetch-api-to-load-wordpress-posts/